# TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined

Tags: angular, tinymce

when using the setContent function of TinyMCE I get this error:
TypeError: Can not read property 'parse' of undefined

Here is my code below:

component.ts:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {   
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    plugins: ['link', 'image'],
    language: this.translation.translate('filiais.empresa.idioma-editor'),
    height: 500,     
    setup: editor => {
      this.editor = editor;
      editor.on('keyup', () => {
        const content = editor.getContent();
        this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
      })    
    }   
  });   
}

private preencherEmpresa(empresa) {
  this.empresa = new Empresa(
    empresa.empre_codigo, empresa.empre_nome,
    empresa.empre_cnpj, empresa.empre_endereco,
    empresa.empre_termos, empresa.empre_bundle,
    empresa.empre_cdn
  );   
  this.editor.setContent(empresa.empre_termos);
}
```

Comment: What is `empresa.empre_termos`?

Comment: Can you show the constructor of the `Emresa` class and the code within the `setContent` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're using the regular version (pure JS) of TinyMCE. The problem is that it's outside Angular's world, and Angular has no idea it's here, so it can't work well.

You need to [integrate it with Angular](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/)

Comment: Ok, I tried doing the integration, but I get the following error:

Error: Template parse errors:
'editor' is not a known element:

Comment: I got it, thank you!
Now I would like to know one more thing:
I saw in the configuration that [init] receives the configuration. How can I read the component.ts variables in this directive?
I tried putting [init] = "configEditor" but without success.

Comment: Ah, glad you could make it :)

Comment: Same issue/solution for vue 3